# How can the same expression be evaluated differently?

Tags: java, string, boolean, equals

Can someone please shed some light on this sick sorcery:

```
    System.out.println(("a".equals("a")));  //true
    System.out.println(("a".equals("а")));  //false

    System.out.println(("Joachim Garraud" == "Joachim Garraud"));       //true
    System.out.println(("Joachim Garraud" == "Joаchim Garraud"));       //false
    System.out.println(("Joachim Garraud".equals("Joаchim Garraud")));  //false
    System.out.println(("Joachim Garraud".equals("Joachim Garraud")));  //true
```

I have no idea what is going on here, but I swear I get these results. I really don't see any difference, and the results are consistent - also when I copy a "false-line", I get false again and vice versa.

Comment: Try to run it again and see what you get. They all should be `true`.

Comment: If this is not just you trolling us, please provide some information on the JVM used. Also try and convert the strings to byte arrays using a unicode encoding like UTF-8 and compare those arrays.

Comment: Sorry, your results are simply not possible.

Comment: @WATTOStudios - they ARE possible, and indeed this is not the first time that this topic has come up on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Stephen, I'm willing to backtrack on my answer, but how is it possible that `"a".equals("a")` is false?

Comment: @Watto - exactly my question. I tried to make it not look like trolling, but I still got downvoted :/ Check my comments below for more info about the bytes there.

Comment: Not sure what happened with cut and paste and all, but I submitted an edit to the problem that reproduces it with a Cyrilic 'a'.

Comment: @WATTOStudios - my answer gives one possible explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also look for non displayable characters.

```
System.out.println("<\ufff9\ufffa\ufffb>");
System.out.println("<￹￺￻>");
System.out.println("<￹￺￻>".length());
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("<￹￺￻>".toCharArray()));
```

appears like this

```
<>
<>
5
[<, ￹, ￺, ￻, >]
```

Copy this into your IDE and those characters will not appear, but they are there. ;)

Comment: The BOM caused the problem (more info in my answer), and since it is a non displayable character, I've updated this to be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that the cause is that your code contains different versions of (for instance) the `"a"` character.  For instance, a lower-case LATIN A could look identical to a lower-case CYRILIC A ... but they are different Unicode code points (`\u0061` versus `\u0430`), and therefore not equal.

Comment: Looks like that was it, you can check my comment to @Old Pro's answer to see the bytes I got with `getBytes()`. Thanks.
I will choose your answer as the accepted one since that must be what happened (although I'm still quite confused because I typed the _a_'s myself). I wish I could also give credit to @Thomas and @Old Pro who solved this with the byte arrays tips, though.

Answer (score 3):

After printing out the binary codes of the strings (as suggested by Thomas and Old Pro), it finally turned out that [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) was what caused the inequality:

```
for( byte b : "a".getBytes() ) { // The first "a" copied from the false-expression
    System.out.printf("%x ", b);
}
for( byte b : "a".getBytes() ) { // The second "a" copied from the false-expression
    System.out.printf("%x ", b);
}

// Again, copied from the false-evaluating expression:
for( byte b : "Joachim Garraud".getBytes() ) {
    System.out.printf("%x ", b);
}
for( byte b : "Joachim Garraud".getBytes() ) {
    System.out.printf("%x ", b);
}
```

...caused the following output: (printouts aligned for better readability)

```
ef bb bf 61
         61

ef bb bf 4a 6f 61 63 68 69 6d 20 47 61 72 72 61 75 64 
         4a 6f 61 63 68 69 6d 20 47 61 72 72 61 75 64
```

Now I can understand this with *Joachim Garraud* since I got those "two" from two different .txt files -- the first was at the beginning of the first file and the second was somewhere in the middle of the second file. **However**, I typed the *a*'s myself, but don't remember anymore how exactly I did it -- maybe I copy-pasted the piece of code with the false-evaluating expression and then Just deleted *Joachim Garraud* inside the quotes and typed *a*, which did not delete the BOM.

Anyway, I hope something can be learnt from this. Also, the guy got a lot of free advertisement here for nothing (actually for the BOM), though I thought he was the new Chuck Norris of some kind. Not a fan or anything.

Comment: Yea ... you should have used "Jon Skeet".  He'd the official Chuck Norris of SO :-)

Answer (score 2):

I have little idea what's going on either, as when I copied all your code every line printed `true`.

So copy it all back to your machine and everything should be fixed.

If I had to guess, I'd guess that one of the "a" characters had a diacritical mark that was being mapped by your display font into a character that did not have the mark.

Next time print out the binary code of the strings in hex and compare them.

Comment: I guess this was it:
`System.out.println(("a".getBytes())); // [B@18fe7c3    
    System.out.println(("a".getBytes())); // [B@b8df17    
          
    System.out.println(("Joachim Garraud".getBytes())); //   [B@13e8d89    
    System.out.println(("Joachim Garraud".getBytes())); // [B@1be2d65    `  

But the strange thing is that the "a"'s were typed in. The "Joachim" thing was from a file, but I typed the "a"'s myself to check this craziness... It drove me nuts.
Anyways, thanks for the byte-checking tips guys.

Comment: That's a little helpful, but not much.  All you did there was show that they were different objects.  You did not print out the contents of the byte array.

Comment: Oh, right. Why did I think...oh well. Thanks for pointing that out, now that I have really printed them out, I understand what was happening there. Writing the answer now.